# Google Chrome Icons Blank

Tags: 14.04, unity, google-chrome

I Imported by bookmarks from a html file(previously exported from google chrome) to google chrome, now the icons are showing blanks. There are a couple dozen icons still showing out of several thousand.  How can I restore     the blank icons of the bookmarks I have saved (imported) to the original icons representing the website of the bookmark?
 Also all my icons in my bookmark bar are showing their icons representing the website for that bookmark.

Comment: Do the icons reappear if you open the bookmarked websites"for the first time" ?

Comment: Yes they reappear if I open a bookmark for the first time.(I have to close chrome and then when I reopen chrome and check the bookmark I previously opened the icon is back for that website.)  Also for people who have this issue and don't have to many bookmarks they can open a whole folder at a time by right clicking on a folder within bookmarks manager.  Then selecting open all bookmarks.  When done restart chrome.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to revisiting all the links would be to use `chrome://settings/syncSetup` in the chrome address bar if you have a Google account. Note: you have to be signed into your Google Account for this to work.

**Edit:**

Some other (untested by me) alternatives include:

`rm ~/.config/google-chrome/Local\ State` The file exists and it seems plausible. Answer found [here](https://superuser.com/a/739883/357362)

Another option is to install and use the plugin [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh).

Sources:

https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/2914794?hl=en

https://superuser.com/questions/375321/how-to-refresh-bookmark-favicons-in-chrome

Comment: @Linuxuser001 updated answer

Comment: I tried Bookmark Favicon Changer again and I was unable to restore favicons.  I deleted local state, restarted google chrome and rebooted computer, but it did not restore my favicons.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of fixing this is to give a chance to the free open source project [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)), since it seems you're going to start over with your browser's settings.

Chromium is faster and it comes with no Google spying within.

I never had any problems with Chromium. I moved my settings many times to many other computers, but it's up to you to judge how good really is. Please give it a try to see for yourself. It has exactly the same plugins and extensions and the interface is almost the same.

It comes without Pepper Flash plugin pre-installed but it can be installed manually or from the software center easily.

***Google's Chrome Privacy Policy:*** https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/

Answer (score -2):

If the issue is with your favicons, then
you have several options.

1. Try deleting the cache in your browser  and restarting Chrome.
2. Opening each bookmark individually should fix the issue.
3. If you imported the bookmarks from a different computer then copy the favicon file from that system and place it in the appropriate directory on the new system.

Not sure if you came from a Windows, Mac or Linux system and moved to Ubuntu or not.

Comment: Can you explain your first answer.  I don't have some directories above.  My favicons are located:            /home/user/.cache/transmission/favicons

Comment: @Linuxuser001 To the best of my knowledge the reference on point 1 is to a Windows path and is only relevant if the OP exported from Windows and still has the previous filesystem. [Reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q7j48jI1b6k) Points 2 and 3 appear to be valid however.

Comment: I edited my answer. I made the mistake of pointing directly to a Windows file. I will try to be more generic in the future. Thanks